# How to perform Null check for react compiler

Tags: reactjs, typescript, null

I'm trying to write a function in React and am getting the error
`Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)`
What I want to know is how to do a null check that allows the me use the object without the compiler complaining.

I've tried different forms of if statements and none have worked.

```
function clickedOutsideViewForm(ref: React.MutableRefObject<null>) {
        console.log("ref", ref)
        function handleClickOutside(event: MouseEvent) {
                                    VVVV Here is the error
          if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
            setFormState({ newViewText: '', isUsingForm: false, cloneOf: undefined });
          }
        }

        React.useEffect(() => {
          document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
          return () => {
            // Unbind the event listener on clean up
            document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
          };
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function arguments, `ref` is being assigned `React.MutableRefObject<null>` so it will always be null.

You need to include the HTML type, for example `React.MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | null>`.